# Routing Traffic from PPTP VPN Server to OpenVPN Client on tun0

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn, iptables, pptp

Thanks for taking the time to help me out. I'm trying to setup a routing between the traffic I get from my PPTP VPN Service on (ppp0) and route it to my OpenVPN (tun0) Interface. I have tried multiple solutions from various answers on the past couple of days, and have so far been unable to get it working.

**What I'm Trying to Achieve**

```
My Device -> ppp0 -> tun0 -> Internet
```

**OpenVPN Client Configuration**

I've added `route-noexec` to ensure I can SSH into the server without the client overwriting the IP tables.

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote 185.244.215.195 443
resolv-retry infinite
remote-random
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
persist-key
persist-tun
ping 15
ping-restart 0
ping-timer-rem
reneg-sec 0
comp-lzo no
verify-x509-name CN=us-ca90.nordvpn.com

remote-cert-tls server

auth-user-pass
route-noexec
```

**My Current IP Tables Setup**

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE && iptables-save
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I INPUT -s 10.0.0.1/24 -i ppp0 -j ACCEPT
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

**Further Debug Information**

Using the above I can go ahead and ping my server at it's DHCP Assigned IP of `10.0.0.50` and on the Server I can go ahead and do `curl --interface tun0 ipinfo.io` and it's working with the OpenVPN Tunnel.

**Gateway**: 10.0.0.1
**Local IP**: 10.0.0.50

**`ip route show`**

```
default via 10.0.0.1 dev enp0s6 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.50 metric 100 
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp0s6 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.50 metric 100 
10.0.0.1 dev enp0s6 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.50 metric 100 
10.0.0.100 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1 
10.7.0.0/16 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.7.0.7 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s6 scope link 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s6 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.50 metric 100 
169.254.169.254 via 10.0.0.1 dev enp0s6 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.50 metric 100
```

**`iptables-save` output**

```
root@instance-20231012-1109:/home/ubuntu# ./build-tun0.sh
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Fri Oct 13 05:33:11 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [103:10600]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [64:53484]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Oct 13 05:33:11 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Fri Oct 13 05:33:11 2023
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [5796:1077692]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3072:143043]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [247:17909]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [40:3581]
-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Oct 13 05:33:11 2023
```

Comment: I think you really mean to an OpenVPN *server* that someone else operates? Please share the full output of `iptables-save`. Also make sure you have enabled IP forwarding with sysctl.

Comment: @TomYan Thank You so much for helping me out, I have added the `iptables-save` output, and I have also made sure that `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` is enabled. If I change my configuration to `enp0s6` instead of `tun0` it works.

Comment: Actually, assuming the traffics from the pptp are for the Internet (i.e., you want to use the openvpn server the pptp server is connected to as the Internet gateway for the pptp client), you'll need a default route that uses `tun0` anyway. If you need to "split tunnel", you'll need an alternate route table for the route and policy routing (e.g. ip rule that matches `iif ppp0`). (But strangely in your ip route output, there's not even a ppp0 route; have you omitted some lines?)

Comment: Hi @TomYan the `ppp0` interface becomes active on `nmcli` and `ip route show` when a user connects to it, so I've updated the post to include the newly added `ip route show` with `ppp0` enabled. Thanks a lot for the time to help me out.

Comment: @TomYan I would also like to add when I connect I can only access the local network *no access to the internet from tun0*.